# How to use ssc.filestream() to handle a zip directory in Java

Tags: zip, spark-streaming

I am new in Spark Streaming.

I want to monitor and unzip all .zip files in a specific directory.
I have referenced http://cutler.io/2012/07/hadoop-processing-zip-files-in-mapreduce/ and write the following code

```
JavaPairInputDStream<Text, BytesWritable> streamlogFiles=ssc.fileStream(logDir, Text.class, BytesWritable.class, ZipFileInputFormat.class);
```

However, I found that fileStream() do not handle the zip file exsitedin /moved into the specified directory.

Is there anything I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ZipFileInputFormat here: https://github.com/cotdp/com-cotdp-hadoop/tree/master/src/main/java/com/cotdp/hadoop

and create a fileStream using

```
val files = ssc.fileStream[Text, BytesWritable, ZipFileInputFormat](someInputDirectory)

files.foreachRDD{ rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partition =>
    partition.foreach { record =>
      process(record._1.toString, record._2)
    }
  }
}
```

Where `record._1.toString` is the filename as `record._2` are the BytesWriteable for that file. If you don't want the InputFormat to unzip the .zip, you'll need a different custom FileInputFormat or have to modify ZipFileInputFormat.

For testing this - make sure the .zip file you're adding to `someInputDirectory` was last modified < 1 minute ago, otherwise SparkStreaming will ignore it by default.